# How to turn off tracing events emitted by other crates?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

I use [tracing](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/), and I only want to see my own debug events. However, some crates I depend on also have tracing support, and they litter the event stream. So when I increase verbosity to `DEBUG`, I see a lot of these in my logs:

```
2022-08-04T20:52:24.523161Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::io: flushed 1008 bytes
```

I tried to turn off these events by adding spans around such calls:

```rust
let response = {
    let span = tracing::info_span!("my_span");
    let _guard = span.enter();
    client
        // set up the request
        .send()
        .await
};
```

I expected those 3rd party `DEBUG` events to go away since the span's verbosity level is `INFO`. But they remained. The [docs of spans](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/span/index.html) is a little light on what the verbosity level of a span really means, so my interpretation might be totally off.

How do I set the verbosity level for dependent crates, so only my own `DEBUG` events appear in the trace logs?

I set the verbosity level using the environment variable `RUST_LOG=debug`, and I set up tracing-subscriber like this:

```rust
tracing_subscriber::fmt::init();
```

Relevant part of `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
tracing = "0.1.36"
tracing-subscriber = { version = "0.3", features = ["env-filter"] }
```

Comment: The `tracing`-crate is only concerned with producing events; some other crate is tasked with generating actual logs from those events. That crate (e.g. `tracing-subscriber`) will have knobs and switches to filter log events. You may want to update your question wrt that, e.g. posting your cargo manifest.

Comment: Thanks, that's already very helpful. So if I understand correctly, events are emitted regardless of the verbosity levels of either the events or the spans. And it's the subscriber that needs to filter those events, right? I added details to the question.

Comment: In that case, see [here](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/0.3.15/tracing_subscriber/fmt/index.html#filtering-events-with-environment-variables) and [here](https://docs.rs/env_logger/latest/env_logger/#enabling-logging) on how to filter logging output to just your crate/module

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you use `tracing_subscriber::fmt::init()` with the `"env-filter"` feature enabled so it reads from your environment, you already have all the pieces you need to filter the logs to your liking.

You can simply set `RUST_LOG` like so (insert your own crate for "mycrate"):

```
RUST_LOG=none,mycrate=debug
```

This will disable logging for all tracing events, unless they come from "mycrate" which will be logged if they are at the DEBUG level or higher. You can read the documentation for `EnvFilter` [Directives](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/filter/struct.EnvFilter.html#directives) for more customization.

Comment: this means that you need to explicitly whitelist every tracing target in your project, right? The default behavior is one target per module, so you would need to configure hundreds of such directives.

Comment: @DerekThurn The above with `=none` prefixed would imply a whitelist mechanism, yes. But you don't have to list every *module* you intend to allow, only every *crate*. I understood OP desired only wanted to see events from their own crate(s) so a whitelist would work better. You could flip it to be like a blacklist if you want: `=debug,h2=error` (allow all debug events, except only errors from the h2 crate).

Answer (score 2):

To do this programmatically:

```rust
// as a deny filter (DEBUG, but remove noisy logs)
let filter = EnvFilter::builder()
    .with_default_directive(LevelFilter::DEBUG.into())
    .from_env()?
    .add_directive("hyper::proto=info".parse()?);

// or as an allow list (INFO, but drill into my crate's logs)
let filter = EnvFilter::builder()
    .with_default_directive(LevelFilter::INFO.into())
    .from_env()?
    .add_directive("mycrate=debug".parse()?);

tracing_subscriber::fmt()
    .with_env_filter(filter)
    .compact()
    .init();
```

The `add_directive()` method takes a `Directive` which you could also create based on a command line parameter if you're writing a CLI tool.